# PHP/MySQL: list And explode Multiple Characters

Tags: php, mysql, list, explode

This is something that I've mostly finished and I'm wondering if there's a way to clean up the code and to get to function correctly.

I have a table with the date and time a user joined (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). I was wanting to split up the various values so I used both the `list` `explode` functions, but was only able to split one group of values:

```
$joined = $row ["joined"]; // <- "2008-06-03 15:01:08"
list ($year, $month, $day) = explode ("-", $joined);
list ($hour, $minute, $second) = explode (":", $joined);
list ($seperation) = explode (" ", $joined);
echo $joined . "<br>\n";
echo $year . "<br>\n";
echo $month . "<br>\n";
echo $day . "<br>\n";
echo $hour . "<br>\n";
echo $minute . "<br>\n";
echo $second . "<br>\n";
```

The following was the output:

```
2008-06-03 15:01:08 ($joined)
2008 ($year)
06 ($month)
03 15:01:08 ($day)
2008-06-03 15 ($hour)
01 ($minute)
08 ($second)
```

I'm wanting to know how I can explode the 3 characters (the dash, colon and space) to be able to use the variables correctly and have it look like the following:

```
2008-06-03 15:01:08 ($joined)
2008 ($year)
06 ($month)
03 ($day)
15 ($hour)
01 ($minute)
08 ($second)
```

Comment: Did the provided solution work?

Comment: Just checked. It did. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$year = date("Y", strtotime($joined));
$month = date("m", strtotime($joined));
$day = date("d", strtotime($joined));
$hour = date("H", strtotime($joined));
$minute = date("i", strtotime($joined));
$second = date("s", strtotime($joined));
```

Or a better solution:

```
$date = getdate(strtotime($joined));
```

When dealing with dates it is best to use date parsing instead of `explode`, or regex. The above uses `strtotime()` to convert the date string into Unix timestamp and then outputs them based on the date patterns.

And the second solution is much better as it returns an associative array of time fields.

But if you really do want to use `list()` and `explode`, here is a solution.

```
list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $joined);
list ($year, $month, $day) = explode ("-", $date);
list ($hour, $minute, $second) = explode (":", $time);
```

It separates date and time first, and then uses `explode` on them separately.

Comment: Instead of calling `date()` and `strtotime()` multiple times, use `getdate(strtotime($joined))`. It returns an associative array with all the fields of the time.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, very good solution, I will include this in the answer too.